# Calculate the asymptotic distribution for coefficient of variation of a LogNorm

Tags: statistics

I want to use the Delta Method to find the asymptotic distribution of the MLE of the coefficient of variation of a LogNormal variable:

[ $X\sim LN(\mu,\sigma) \Rightarrow f(X)=\frac{1}{\sigma x \sqrt{2 \pi}}\exp(-\frac{(ln(x)-\mu)^2)}{2 \sigma^2})$ ]

I have found that the MLE for $\mu$ is $\bar{\mu}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}$ and that the MLE for $\sigma$ is $\bar{\sigma}=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{\mu})^2}{n}}$.

I've also found that $\bar{\mu}\sim N(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ and $\bar{\sigma}\sim N(\sigma, \frac{\sigma^2}{2n})$

The problem is that I don't know what function do I have to use for the Delta Method.
I thought about using $g(x)=\frac{\sigma}{x}$ or $g(x)=\frac{\sigma}{ln(x)}$ but I'm not sure if one of this is correct or I should use another one.

ANY IDEAS?

(I would be gratefull if you develop the process so I can compare it with mine once I do it)

Comment: The function is the coeffcient of variation: $g(\sigma,\mu)=\frac{\sigma}{\mu}$, to which you can apply the "delta method".

Comment: I thought about doing that but I don't know how to use the delta method with two variables

Comment: You need to write out a bivariate Taylor's expnasion :-)